# How can I place text content under my images without breaking the structure?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to place some text content under each of the images in a gallery but I carnt get the text to be Bellow the image instead of at the side

http://jsfiddle.net/9YE3H/

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Put each image and paragraph in a single div like such:

```
<div>
   <img src="" />
   <br />
   <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

This should work for you, as long as you haven't set the float attribute for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this. One would be using [tables](http://w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) and put this in the td-tags:

```
<div>
   <img src="images/search_images/musicians/adele.jpg" width="175" height="176" /><br />
   <p>Artist: Adele</p>
   <p>Genre: Singer-Songwriter</p>
</div>
```

Another one would be using that combined with either [positioning](http://w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) or more preferably [floating](http://w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways, but I would say use some divs to make individual container layouts for each image / text item.

```
  <div class="img-container-class">
      <img src="img address here" />
      <div class="img-text-class">
         <p>Artist: Person</p>
         <p>Genre: Genre Type</p>
      </div>                  
  </div>
```

Now the "img-text" class isn't totally necessary. But, sometimes I feel it is a good idea to section off the text area a bit more, so that you can do some more specific changes to the text (that's up to you).

Personally, I would go back and revamp some of those styles. While looking at the snippet you posted I noticed that almost all of the elements have "float:left" attached to them, as well as a lot of mixing of margin and padding. I would say, start simple, float the div that is holding both the image and text, and then let the normal flow take over from there. Once you get that containing structure set then I think you will find quite a few style sections you can trim down.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest effective approach is probably a single-cell table, with the text in the `caption` element, e.g.

```
<table class=img callpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<caption align=bottom>
Artist: Adele<br>
Genre: Singer-Songwriter dcccc
</caption>
<tr><td><img
  src="images/search_images/musicians/adele.jpg"
  alt="(Adele)" width="175" height="176"></td>
</table>
```

This is particularly convenient if you want to display many images side by side, so that the amount of images in a row is not fixed but gets adjusted according to window width. In that case you would just set `align=left` on the `table` elements and probably set some right margin for them.